# FB.login() results in auto-login popup before on-click

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm developing sns login page. 
I use custom login-button and FB.login().
Suddenly, I encounted unsuspected problem that FB.login() resulted in auto-login popup before I click login button..

I do Not want pop-up login window before click the login-button...!!

How can I fix this problem?? Help me..plz....ㅜㅜ

this is my url!
http://sangji.dothome.co.kr/index2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
            FB.init({ 
                appId: 'myAppKey', 
                status: true, 
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                oauth: true,
                version    : 'v2.5'
            });
            fbLoginStatus();
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ko_KR/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


        function fbLoginStatus(){
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
                    console.log(access_token);
                } else {
                    fblogin();
                }
            });
        }

        function fblogin(){
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
                    console.log(access_token);
                } else {
                    console.log('Authorization failed.');
                }
            },{ //permissions
                scope: 'email'
            });
        }
        </script>

    <a href="#" onclick="fblogin();"><img src="fb_bt.png"></a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: read this carefully: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Answer (score 0):

You are calling 'fblogin' in the callback to `getLoginStatus` - this in turn is calling `FB.login` which is based on opening a popup.